# Where can I find AniMove in Qgis2.4

Tags: qgis

I have sucessfully installed AniMove by activating experimental plugins (yay! thanks gis.stackexchange). But I can't find it in Qgis! Yes I have activated it. Where is it? Is this a common bug? I searched for it the toolbox, I looked up the names of the several single tools based on this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98ORgGX8vSM) and only found "Kernel Density", which is filed under SAGA. But I don't have SAGA installed (and don't know if I need to?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go into Processing -> Options and Configuration
2. Under the Providers section find Animove
3. Under Animove check Activate

Now you'll see it in the Processing toolbox.
[image]